# migrating from wss3 to sharepoint foundation 2010

Tags: 2010, migration

I have a question but not sure if I explain well because I do not even understand exactly what I need. I need to migrate a sites (I do not know who they worked or how, this is on my job, I'm newbie there of course).

I started with this steps (https://win1337ist.wordpress.com/2011/03/08/exporting-and-importing-sites-between-wss-3-and-sharepoint-foundation-2010/= ) but when I try to import that database, I can't because is too big.

We have an express version of 2010 where is allowed only cca 10 GB for database and ours is bigger of course.

We have that SharePoint on one server and I'm trying migrate websites with webdeployment tool from II6 to II7.

My question is, is it possible to migrate that database on server on which we have enough space(another one), and than on server where sites needs to be have just some link to that other server where database is and use that on this way ?!

Does this question even make sense or am I confused something. For even itself I do not know exactly what to do or some such thing in question. Because, honestly have no idea about all this and at work I have to do.

Thank you for any kind of suggest.

Comment: you want to migrate from wss 3 to wss4.0, right? what is sql version in the wss3.0 and size of Content DB? what is target farm's sql server and farm topolgy?

Comment: This isn't usually my area, I just know I must to explore how to do this nothing else. Thing is, we have sharepoint with sql 2003 server and we have some web application witch running on IIS6, and we need to migrate this on sharepoint server 2010, sql server 2008 (again, I think) which have IIS7. I need to explore how create a new web application on that IIS7 but database for this application is to big for that server so I was thinking , can database be on server 2014 and than web application on server 2010 to link to that another server 2014 where would be that database.

Comment: I will ask tomorow on my work for more detailed explanation, than I can tell you. What do I need to ask that I can tell you later so yu can understand my question, what information exactly ?

Comment: check my answer and ask me what you missing

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to access the sharepoint in both farm( central admin as well as SQL access).what you have to do.

- [Create a WebApplication at SPF2010 farm](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/sharepoint-2010-creating-web-application/)
- You need to configure the customization, authnetication and AAM settings.
- Now Backup the Database from SQL server 2003 and restore it to SPF 2010 Databae. If your DB size is greater than the supported on SQL express then you need to restore it to the full version of SQL( 2008/2012/2014).
- Now you have to detach the old database from the web app you created on step 1, [mount the newly restored DB to that web app](http://mysharepointwork.blogspot.com/2010/04/adding-content-database-using.html)
- once you mount it, test it.

You dont need to manually move the IIS sites, in SharePoint everything reside in the Content DB. SO you just need to move the Content DBs.

Check this guide: http://sharepointgeorge.com/2009/upgrading-content-database-sharepoint-2010-database-attach-method/

Comment: ok, thanks, how to configure AAM settings? and how to restore database ? and what if database is still larger ?  I will try this tomorow on work and tell you where I got stuck.... Thanky you very much

Comment: do you have SharePoint Admin in the office, who can access the Central Admin site of the SharePoint farm? link at the end of my ans give the detail how to restore.

Comment: We all can access the Central Admin site for now....

Comment: check this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/configure-an-alternate-access-mapping-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: Great, I will try and explore all of this tomorow on my work.... Maybe than will be all of this clearer in my head :)

Comment: hopefully, their are tons of video avaible on youtube, you can check those as well....